# Send notifications with Rabbitmq

Tags: django, rabbitmq, django-rest-framework, long-polling

I'm using django, django rest framework and Rabbitmq,What I want is using Rabbitmq to send notifications to client after user create a comment(like long polling).
I follow the [RabbitMQ Tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) here.

Here is my view.py to create comments:

```
class CommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #use pika and rabbitmq to notifity user
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
        message = 'Hello, world'
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                              routing_key='task_queue',
                              body=message,
                              properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                 delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
                              ))
        connection.close()        
        return super().create(request, args, kwargs)
```

I create a queue call "task_queue", and sent message "Hello, world" every time I create I comment.

Here is my view.py to receive message:

```
def get_notifications(request):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        return HttpResponse("ok")
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

    #channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='task_queue')

    channel.start_consuming()
```

In client side, I use a jquery ajax function to request data:

```
function poll() {
    var poll_interval=0;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/sub", //sub calls get_notifications()
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            append_circle();
            poll_interval=0;
        },
        error: function () {
            poll_interval=1000;
        },
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(poll, poll_interval);
        },
    });
}
```

I can send the message after I create the comment, but my client side doesn't receive any data, in my chrome console, I find this:

```
sub/    (pending)   xhr
```

What should I do?

Comment: This isn't really what rabbitmq is for.

Comment: So I should use django-socketio or django channels instead?

Answer (score 4):

For this type of application, websockets are the better option. I suggest you to use websockets instead of long polling. Because long polling is resource hungry process. To use websockets, you can use [channels](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)